# Xcode: UI API called from background thread

Tags: xcode, react-native

I'm getting this runtime error below in Xcode 9.2:

[image: GMSisApplicationInBackground]

I'm guessing it's related to a Google library - any ideas how I can debug this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There error was being caused by an older version of Google Maps iOS SDK. By upgrading the SDK to V 2.5.0 the error has been resolved.